# Entering values into a combobox

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have made a combo box to allow me to select a list of values however everytime I select the value this error message appears:

'The field is too small to accept the amount of data you have attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data'

This will come up when i also try and exit the form. The data which i have added to the linked table is:

```
Code: TFS
Short code: FS
Branch: Flooring Shop
Address:
PostCode:
Phone Number:
```

The coding which I have used for the combo box is:

```
Private Sub branchComboBox_Click()

End Sub
```

```
Row Source type: Browser FilterBranch
Row Source: Table/Query
```

Thanks in advance 
Dominique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by a disconnect between your form and your table.

Namely, your combo box is attempting to put data that is too long for the underlying table. If you attempt to add a longer string of text than your table design allows, then the error you are seeing will occur.

You should check your table design and make sure that Branch allows enough characters for what you are attempting to add. If you are supposed to be using a code, and "Browser FilterBranch" is a query that includes the code as a column, make sure your combobox's `Bound Column` is assigned correctly.